# How do I differentiate $3x/(x^2+1)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I kind of understand how the power rule works. You multiply N and subtract 1 from N in the exponent. How do I differentiate
$$y=\frac{3x}{x^2+1}$$

Comment: use quotient rule. https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/derivatives-rules.html

Comment: Advice: if you _kind of_ understand the power rule, study it more carefully until you _really_ understand it. Then take a look at for example the product rule. Then the quotient rule, you'll need that here (together with the power rule!). Don't go too fast - make sure you _really get_ a rule before studying a new one.

Comment: You can also use chain rule or differentiate $\ln y$ (the latter is valid only for $x>0$ unless you are differentiating over $\Bbb C$, so be careful if you need  the derivative for a rigurous proof).

Answer (score 1):

You use the Quotient Rule.
$$\biggr(\frac{f}{g}\biggr)’ = \frac{f’g-g’f}{g^2} \text{   if   } g^2 \neq 0$$
Here, $f$ means $f(x)$ and $g$ means $g(x)$, so simply, they are two functions.

Your function is $$y = \frac{3x}{x^2+1}.$$ You can solve it by breaking it down into $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and then using the Quotient Rule.

$$\text{Say   } f(x) = 3x \text{   and   } g(x) = x^2+1 \text{   so that   } y = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.$$

$$y’ = \biggr(\frac{3x}{x^2+1}\biggr)’ = \frac{(3x)’\cdot(x^2+1)-(x^2+1)’\cdot3x}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx} 3x = 3 \text{   and   } \frac{d}{dx} (x^2+1) = 2x$$

Simplify.

$$y’ = \frac{3\cdot(x^2+1)-2x\cdot(3x)}{(x^2+1)^2} \implies y’ = \frac{3x^2+3-6x^2}{(x^2+1)^2} \implies \boxed{y’ = \frac{-3(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2}}$$

There isn’t really any good simplification from here on, so just leave the answer in factored form.

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate function which is fraction of two functions of $x$, i.e; of the form $y=u(x)/v(x)$, then, $$y'=\frac{v(x)\cdot\frac{du(x)}{dx}-u(x)\cdot\frac{dv(x)}{dx}}{v(x)^2}$$

See [here](http://web.mit.edu/wwmath/calculus/differentiation/quotients.html) for more detailed proof.

Here, you have $u(x)=3x$ and $v(x)=x^2+1$, as, you know how to differentiate exponents of $x$, $\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=2x$. Just plug in the values.

Answer (score 0):

you have the function:
$$y=\frac{3x}{x^2+1}$$
you really have two options, to use the "product rule + chain rule" or to use the combined "quotient rule". I will use the quotient rule which states for a function:
$$y=\frac{u}{v}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{v\frac{du}{dx}-u\frac{dv}{dx}}{v^2}$$
so if:
$$y=\frac{3x}{x^2+1}$$
then:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x^2+1)(3)-(3x)(2x)}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{3-3x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{3(1-x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

Lets now try and take a different approach:

as I mentioned earlier there are two other rules, the chain rule:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}*\frac{du}{dx}$$
and the product rule:
$$y=f(x)g(x)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$
we can then view our function instead as:
$$y=(3x)(x^2+1)^{-1}$$
and use a combination of these two rules